# add number to date field in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

i have 2 fields in the database (sql server 08)
Dob = "05/09/1965"
license_age = 16
how do i get the number of years this person hs had licence.
so basically dim age1 = current year - (dob - license_age)
thanks

-- thanks for the answers. worked perfectly. another question based on this.
how do i find out which year he got his license based on the above two fields?

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim dob As DateTime = GetDobFromDb()
Dim licAge As Integer = GetLicAgeFromDb()

Dim age1 As TimeSpan = DateTime.Today - dob.AddYears(licAge)
```

Comment: worked perfectly. another question based on this. how do i find out which year he got his license based on the above two fields?